# Wrong step in linear equations with fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to resolve this equation:

$\frac{n-5}{6n-6}=\frac19-\frac{n-3}{4n-4}$

The answer is: $n=\frac{53}{11}$

However, after spending hours trying to solve this and fixing the mistakes I can only come up with $n=-\frac{18}{24}$, which is obvious not the right answer, but I cannot pinpoint the problem on the following steps:

Step 1: Multiply each statement by the LCD in this case $(6n-6)(9)(4n-4)$

$(6n-6)(9)(4n-4)\frac{n-5}{6n-6}=(6n-6)(9)(4n-4)\frac19-(6n-6)(9)(4n-4)\frac{n-3}{4n-4}$

Step 2: Simplifying by cancelling like terms:

$(9)(4n-4)(n-5)=(6n-6)(4n-4)-(6n-6)(9)(n-3)$

Step 3: Let's Multiply !!!

$36n^2-180n-36n+180=24n^2-24n-24n+24-(54n-54)(n-3)$

$36n^2-180n-36n+180=24n^2-48n+24-54n^2-162-54n+162$

Step 4: More cancelation

$-180n-36n+180=-24n-(-18n-6n+18)(9)$
$-180n-36n+180=-24n-216n+162$

$-216n+180=-240n+162$

Step 5: Swapping things around

$-216n+240n=162-180$

$24n=-18$

$n=-\frac{18}{24}$

Comment: You might find it helpful to factor the denominators first. Notice that $6n-6 = 6(n-1)$, and $4n-4 = 4(n-1)$. Do you see how this will simplify your approach?

Comment: @Théophile Thanks for that, I will try it.

Comment: Along the lines of @Théophile: What does the figure $36(n-1)$ have to do with this? Note that $36=4\cdot 9=6\cdot 6=$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Leucippus beat me to it. His solution is much quicker but if you we're having trouble with some in between steps the following should help clear that up.

$\frac{n-5}{6n-6}=\frac19-\frac{n-3}{4n-4}$

You don't necessarily need a lowest common denominator, you simply need a common denominator to add or subtract fractions. In situations similar to this you can do it your way by multiplying everything together at once, but sometimes it is much easier (a.k.a you're less likely to make mistakes) if you do them one at a time.

First, multiply both sides by $(6n-6)$ to get:

$n-5$ = $\frac{6n-6}9$ $-$ $\frac{6n^2-24n+18}{4n-4}$

Now some factoring and reducing:

$\frac{6n-6}9$ = $\frac{6(n-1)}9$ = $\frac{2(n-1)}3$

$\frac{6n^2-24n+18}{4n-4}$ = $\frac{6(n-3)(n-1)}{4(n-1)}$ = $\frac{3(n-3)}2$

Gives us:

$n-5$ = $\frac{2(n-1)}3$ $-$ $\frac{3(n-3)}2$

You can multiply by 3 and then 2 to get rid of the denominators or simply multiply by 6. Same idea you wanted to use originally to eliminate denominators, only now doing two denominators at once is a lot less messy because you only have integers down there.

This leaves you with:

$6(n-5)$ = $4(n-1)$ $-$ $9(n-3)$

From here it is quite straightforward.

$6n-30$ = $4n-4-9n+27$

$11n$ = $53$

Thus, $n$ does in fact equal $\frac{53}{11}$.

Answer (score 3):

The hints are present, but it simply follows the pattern
\begin{align}
\frac{n-5}{6n-6} &= \frac{1}{9} - \frac{n-3}{4n-4} \\
\frac{n-5}{6(n-1)} &= \frac{1}{9} - \frac{n-3}{4(n-1)} \\
\frac{n-5}{6(n-1)} + \frac{n-3}{4(n-1)} &= \frac{1}{9} \\
4(n-5) + 6(n-3) &= \frac{24}{9} (n-1) = \frac{8}{3} (n-1) \\
(4 + 6 -\frac{8}{3} ) n &= 20 + 18 - \frac{8}{3} \\
\frac{22 n}{3} &= \frac{106}{3}
\end{align}
which is
\begin{align}
n = \frac{53}{11}.
\end{align}